# How to plot the poles and zeros of this Bandpass Filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bandpass, digital-filters, poles-zeros

So I'm trying to design a **band pass filter** in MATLAB (with a **center frequency of 10kHz** and a **sampling frequency of 44kHz**).

I have calculated the transfer function but I'm not sure how to enter this transfer function into MATLAB to generate a plot of the frequency and phase responses of the filter, and the poles and zeros.

[image: Band Pass Filter transfer function calculation. Ωc (the cutoff frequency in radians) was already found to be 5pi/11, using the formula Ωc = 2π fc/fs = 2π*10000/44000 = 5π/11.]

It could also be that the transfer function is calculated wrong? I haven't seen the denominator have so many terms before so I'm not sure..

This is my first time posting on SE, so any help is appreciated.

PS: I kinda always thought that the poles of a band pass filter would be pi/2 always, so I guess I was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've designed a second-order band pass filter, so the number of terms in the denominator is just fine (it's a second-order polynomial). Your design is OK, apart from the scaling, i.e., the maximum of the magnitude of the transfer function is not equal to $1$, which might be desirable.

Your transfer function has the form

$$H(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{(z-p)(z-p^*)}=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2-2zr\cos(\omega_p)+r^2}\tag{1}$$

where $p$ is a complex-valued pole:

$$p=re^{j\omega_p}\tag{2}$$

with radius $r$ and pole angle $\omega_p$. Note that in general the pole angle $\omega_p$ and the peak frequency $\omega_0$ (where the magnitude of the frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ achieves its maximum) are not equal. However, in your case they are almost identical because $\omega_p$ is relatively close to $\pi/2$. See [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27015/4298) for more details on this matter.

If you want the frequency response peak value to be equal to $1$, you need to scale your transfer function by the factor $(1-r^2)/2$ (also explained in the answer quoted above).

The pole angle $\omega_p$ depends on the desired center frequency, so it can't always be equal to $\pi/2$ as you seem to have thought (even though in your calculations you chose it according to the desired center frequency).

The Matlab function [freqz](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) computes the complex frequency response of a discrete-time filter.
For plotting the poles and zeros you can use the function [zplane](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/zplane.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Matt! I've read over both your responses and it helped me achieve the desired result. 

But I'm still confused about how to find the gain factor K so the peak gain is 1. By using (1−r^2)/2, I end up getting a peak gain of less than 1. Through trial and error (changing K and looking at the graphs each time), I found the value of K should be about 0.087. 

Here are all of my calculations for clarity: https://imgur.com/a/K7Rj6xX

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks again!

Comment: @NikhilSaxena: Your filter coefficients are correct. The problem must be in the way you plot the frequency response.

Comment: Ah that's good to know. Thank you! 

I've accepted and upvoted the answer now, but since my reputation is less than 15, the upvote won't be shown publicly :)